# Invalid Property Value Css value

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have tried the below CSS in multiple browsers and am not having success using the `grid-template-columns` attribute.

```
.container {
  background-color: azure;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 1fr;
}
```

The CSS is throwing an error indicating the `grid-template-columns` is invalid.

Comment: Drop the `,` 's

Comment: `1fr 1fr 1fr` would do.

Comment: I hardly believe the problem is with your monitor. Leave the innocent monitor alone xD...

Answer (score 4):

That is not the syntax of [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) values. All you need to do is remove the commas.

```css
.container {
  background-color: azure;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```